# Access Textbox inside DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, detailsview

Does anyone have any idea how I can set the text of a textbox inside a DetailsView field (c#)?

I've tried a few variations but all return out of context and object reference not set errors.

Heres my code...

ASPX:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

CS:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1");
txt.Text = "Text ";
```

Cheers

Comment: At what point in your code-behind are you doing this?  Have you checked to make sure there **is** anything in the `DetailsView` before you try to access the `TextBox`?  Because the code you've shown looks ok to me.

Comment: Hi there, Its in Page_Load(), yes theres data in the view, double-checked

Comment: I've also tried referncing via rows and also checked to see there was no dynamically created IDs that was messing things up

Comment: Right, I think you're on the right track with the `Findcontrol` method, I just don't think there's anything in your `DetailsView` at that point.  Put an `if (txt != null)` before the `txt.Text = "Text ";` line, I bet you'll see that it is in fact null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error likely means that there is nothing in your `DetailsView` yet.  I bet if you put this in your code:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1");
if (txt != null)
{
    txt.Text = "Text ";
}
```

You'll see that `txt` is, in fact, `null` - this is because the `FindControl` method didn't find anything named "TextBox1" in the `DetailsView`.

You need to move this code to a point where you know the `DetailsView` has been populated (if it's bound to a `DataSource`, you could do this in the `DataBound` event of your `DetailsView`).

Also, I noticed that your `TextBox` is in an `InsertItemTemplate`.  You won't find that `TextBox1` until you put the `DetailsView` in edit mode, either by default:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px"  
        DefaultMode="Insert">
```

Or in code behind:

```
DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
TextBox txt = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1"); 
txt.Text = "Text ";
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi there, ya theres definately data in the DetailsView. Ive tried adding a plain old html textbox in there too and tried finding that control. No errors but still doesnt populate the box with any data. Strange

Comment: @Developr: I've edited my answer with another possible problem I just thought of.  Let me know if that helps you out =)

Comment: Hi jadarnel27 - no luck unfortunately. I was already ensuring I was in correct mode. are the html controls created before On_Load? Its almost as tho my actions in On_Load are trying to populate controls which dont exist yet

Comment: @Developr: To answer that, I'd need to know what is populating your `DetailsView` (i.e. binding it to an `SQLDataSource`, etc).  Can you post that portion of your code?

Comment: I did get it to work in the end but only within the data_binding event that was attached to it. Its a horrid bit of code to be fair, i've picked it up from someone else. I think I'll leave it at that for now, as the code is too mesy itself to waste anymore time on - I'll just wewrite in the future because I think its the whole page itself being so messy thats the underlying problem. Thanks for all your help and your answer worked perfect in a new project :) Thanks  jadarnel27

Comment: @Developr Ha, I've been there before (inheriting messy code, that is).  Good luck, and I was glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

@jadarnel27 thank you for your information about putting the code in DataBound event. I had similar issue where a textbox value would only pass to DetailsView field (DefaultMode=Insert) with a button click event. I didn't want/need a button.

My scenario: code identifies if detailsview is needed (for insert). If record does not exist based on person selected from dropdown control, their PersonID is preloaded into the Person field of detailsview.

Using FindControl didn't work  but using the following code did WHEN put in DataBound control.

```
// Get person selected from dropdown control and pass to DetailsView first row/cell
txtPerson.Text = Convert.ToString(ddlPersonSelect.SelectedValue);

TextBox tb = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0];
if (tb != null)
{
tb.Text = txtPerson.Text;
}
```

I hope this helps another newbie like me.